# How do I switch pages within a WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF application and I cannot figure out a way to switch pages, even create multiple pages.  All of the questions related to this topic only show how to switch, not create AND switch.

I have already tried to look up the solution, but no proper answer shows up.

Comment: I don't follow why you think the create is so significant, but pages are usually a bad idea anyhow. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-do-not-use-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: Can you elaborate why they "are a bad idea anyhow."?

Comment: Have you considered using the tabcontrol instead?

Comment: Frame and pages come with a memory overhead due to the journal and state preservation mechanisms. In my experience. "Go back" is a fairly common web user sort of requirement but rarely useful for desktop apps.  Frame and pages are best suited to scenarios like a "wizard" workflow where the user has a series of steps to follow and going back a step or two makes sense.  Viewmodel first is very common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`this.NavigationService.Navigate(new PageName());`

Or
`this.NavigationService?.Navigate(new PageName()); //To check if it's not null`

Edit:Sorry, I didn't understand your question correctly.
As I know, you can't just create and navigate to a page. Why can't you just create a page, design it however you want, and then navigate?

Edit2: After some research, I found that you can create your own class and inherit it from Window class.

```
 public class MyPage: Window
    {
       this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;  
       //Add grid  
       this.RootGrid = new Grid()
       {
           //Add TextBox
           TextBox TextBox_Test = new TextBox()
            { Text = "ABC",
              Background = Brushes.Yellow, 
              HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, 
              VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top 
            };
            this.RootGrid.Children.Add(TextBox_Test);
       }
    }
```

You can add rows/columns as well.

```
this.RootGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(20) });
this.RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width= new GridWidth(20) });
```

Then you can navigate to `MyPage` page as I told.
Hope this helps.